# in Nodejs code below, adding to cart is working for the first new items, but, then every item quantity added individually from the other similar item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

adding to cart is working for the first new items, but, then every item quantity added individually from the other similar item?

```
// registered user add anew cart or add to cart //
router.post("/", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  //let olduser = {};
  olduser = await Cart.findOne({userId:req.user.id});
  if(olduser){
    console.log('already found'+ olduser)
    for(var i = 0 ; i < olduser.products.length; i++){
      if(olduser.products[i].productId.toString() == req.body.productId.toString()){   
        //console.log('olduser is an old product'+  olduser);
        olduser.products[i].quantity = Number.parseInt(olduser.products[i].quantity) + Number.parseInt(req.body.quantity);
       
      }else{
        olduser.products.push({productId:req.body.productId, quantity:req.body.quantity})
        //console.log(olduser.products[3].productId);
      };
      
      try {
        olduser = await olduser.save();
        return res.status(201).send(olduser);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    }; 
  }else{
  let cart = {userId:req.user.id,
              products:[{productId:req.body.productId, quantity:req.body.quantity}]
              }
  const newCart = new Cart(cart);
 
  try {
    const savedCart = await newCart.save();
    //console.log("newCart"+newCart)
    res.status(201).json(savedCart);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
}
});
```

when adding item for the first time its ok, but next item added to mongodb individually every time as a new insertion with out adding quantities
i work with NodeJS, express, JavaScript, EJS, CSS,HTML and more, this code is a part of router named cart,js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. you're running a save inside a for loop - almost certainly not what you're trying to do
2. in your for loop, if the item isn't the item being modified, you push the item back into the array.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < olduser.products.length; i++){
      if(olduser.products[i].productId.toString() == req.body.productId.toString()){   
        //console.log('olduser is an old product'+  olduser);
        olduser.products[i].quantity = Number.parseInt(olduser.products[i].quantity) + Number.parseInt(req.body.quantity);
       
      }else{
        olduser.products.push({productId:req.body.productId, quantity:req.body.quantity})
        //console.log(olduser.products[3].productId);
      };
```

I think you just want to remove your `else` branch entirely.

Comment: thank you brother for respond , but save is outside the loop.  and i cant remove unless cause i have two cases

Comment: `olduser = await olduser.save();` is inside the loop and your else clause is also wrong as I mentioned. Finally, because you return inside a loop too - you're probably never even getting to the second element in the array.